# Access buttons in Fragments under ViewPager

Tags: android, button, android-viewpager

I'm learning Android Programming and did lot of search but still could not find a proper answer for my issue.

I'm doing a project to implement a certain number of pages (or Fragments) under a ViewPager. All the pages had same layout with 04 buttons.

My problem is I don't know where to put the setOnClickListener for the buttons to check which button is clicked at which page?

Thanks for any suggestion or clue to solve it.

My project sample is below:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private ViewPager pager;    
private MyPagerAdapter pageAdapter;
private int numPages = 10; //number of pages, could be any number..

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pageAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

}


private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return MyFragment.newInstance(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return numPages;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="4dip" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

MyFragment.java

```
ublic class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private Button btn1;
private Button btn2;
private Button btn3;
private Button btn4;
private TextView currentPage;
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";

public static Fragment newInstance(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle();
    bdl.putInt(EXTRA_MESSAGE, arg0);
    f.setArguments(bdl);

    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int i = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_MESSAGE); //for later use

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    btn1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn3 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn4 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button4);

    currentPage = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pagenumber);
    currentPage.setText("Page number #" + i);

    return v;
}
```

}

fragment_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
    android:text="Button 1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="Button 2" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@id/button2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="Button 3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@id/button3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="98dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="Button 4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pagenumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: set you click listener where you initialize buttons. give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How stupid I am to missing simple solution...This is just what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get the page information from i

> getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_MESSAGE)

, get button information from button instance. add setOnClickListener for each button. For example:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Page:"+i+ " button:1",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick listener should go in the fragment.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

private Button btn1;
private Button btn2;
private Button btn3;
private Button btn4;
private TextView currentPage;
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";

public static Fragment newInstance(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle();
    bdl.putInt(EXTRA_MESSAGE, arg0);
    f.setArguments(bdl);

    return f;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //TODO do stuff here with the clicked buttons.
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int i = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_MESSAGE); //for later use

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    btn1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn3 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn4 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button4);

    currentPage = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pagenumber);
    currentPage.setText("Page number #" + i);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: as for which page it was clicked on that will depend on what you are doing with the clicks. You should be launching another intent if your switching views. In that case just pass the page number with the intent as an extra.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer, I just testing again by putting a toast message inside onClick(View v) but didn't see anything popup. Am I missing something??

Comment: In your toast message make sure you put getFragmentActivity() for the context.

Comment: Your fragment only contains views and click listeners and logic specific to that fragment and UI changes. The heavy lifting should be left up to the activity.

Comment: I was using getActivity() and guess it should be the same, change to getFragmentActivity() is showing error. Anyway, you are right!! I should lift these button processing to activity, not inside fragment which is logically for UI and button listener. Thanks again!!